# How to trust certificates unconditionally when using Alamofire under swift5

Tags: alamofire, swift5

Can anyone tell me how to trust certificates unconditionally when using Alamofire under swift5, thanks.

Comment: could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146797/how-can-i-access-local-https-with-invalid-certificate-with-alamofire/44169463

Comment: @CHAN Thank you very much for your answer, but that method is no longer applicable in swift5

Comment: ignore in what sense?

Comment: @donnywals It may be that I did not express clearly, what I want is to be able to trust the certificate unconditionally, fortunately I already know how to deal with it, thanks.

Comment: How to avoid down-votes on your question? Have a look at [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has good pointers. Consider updating your question accordingly, so that others can up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my answer, I hope it will be helpful to those who encounter the same problem in the future.

```
extension ViewController : URLSessionDelegate {

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

         let urlCredential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)

         completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
    }
}
```

Comment: @IvoMori Thank you, but now I seem to be unable to operate, maybe it will take a while? This is my first time using it. Please advise if there are any deficiencies.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant ___not to forget to accept your own answer___. There's a 48-hours wait period before you can do it. See also [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for more details.